# Need horizintal scrollable navbar with box and image

Tags: html, css

I need a horizontal `navbar` with one picture and a black background which are scrollable. This picture with black background should be over the `navbar` and have to be fixed.

\\!!!EDIT!!!////
[its like i described in my comment to your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk3XA.jpg)

[i hope that is better to understand this black box takes me to an endless night :S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Kbk.jpg)

```css
<head>
<style>
header {
    margin_top: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: verdana;
}

li {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul a.active {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
   }

nav ul a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta lang="de_DE">
<html>
<body>
<header>
 <a href="LINK" target="_blank">
 <img src="######" alt="Picture" align="middle">
 </a>
</header>      
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><b><a class="active" href="LINK">London</a></b></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Nizza</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">California</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Munich</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Mauritius</a></li>
    <li style="float:right" padding-right:"1em"><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div style="padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
<article>
  <h1>City of London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>
</div>
<footer>Copyright © i dont know</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still unsure what you mean by having the picture over the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few unnecessary style rules in your CSS and the most likely culprit is your positioning of your `ul`. I cleaned up your code below and I believe it works as you intended. The `margin_top` in your `header` CSS rule was not a valid property (s/b `margin-top`). Remove the `position` and `top` properties from your `ul` and add a `width: 100%` to your `header`. Also remove the `align="middle"` from your `img` tag--you are already aligning that image using `text-align: center` in your `header` CSS rule.

```css
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: verdana;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul a.active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta lang="de_DE">
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="LINK" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="Picture">
    </a>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><b><a class="active" href="LINK">London</a></b>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nizza</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">California</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Munich</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mauritius</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right" padding-right: "1em"><a href="#">Impressum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div style="padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
    <article>
      <h1>City of London</h1>
      <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <footer>Copyright © i dont know</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, if you want to fix the `header` and `nav` at the top of the screen, the easiest way to do that would be to wrap those within a `div` then use CSS to fix position that div at the top of the screen. I also removed the `div` wrapping your article and added a CSS rule to move the article down so it starts underneath the fixed position of your header & nav.

```css
#fixMe {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: verdana;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul a.active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

article {
  margin-top: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixMe">
  <header>
    <a href="LINK" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="Picture">
    </a>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><b><a class="active" href="LINK">London</a></b>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nizza</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">California</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Munich</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mauritius</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right" padding-right: "1em"><a href="#">Impressum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<article>
  <h1>City of London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>

<footer>Copyright © i dont know</footer>
```

Comment: Wow, i'm very thankful for ur fast answer and cleaning up my mess.

Comment: i will add new screenshots, but now the black background behind the image not till end of my screen, only 75% and the navigation bar too

Comment: omg okay i got it sorry. so much thanks for you here in germany !

Comment: Glad to hear i could help! Please be sure to mark this as your answer if you found it useful. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to  **Dave Cripps**

```css
#fixMe {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: verdana;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul a.active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

article {
  margin-top: 250px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixMe">
  <header>
    <a href="LINK" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="Picture">
    </a>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><b><a class="active" href="LINK">London</a></b>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Nizza</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">California</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Munich</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Mauritius</a>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right" padding-right: "1em"><a href="#">Impressum</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<article>
  <h1>City of London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>

<footer>Copyright © i dont know</footer>
```